# Spring Cloud Netflix apps running on Docker are killed by the container why?

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I am testing some Spring Cloud Netflix microservices running them as individual Docker containers on Windows.

There are quite a few of them, ten or more. The point is that after running some of them 7, 8... the applications' performance start to decline and some of the containers are killed, for instance I see:

```
2017-01-24 14:05:52.165  INFO 5 --- [nfoReplicator-0] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@67b129a3: startup date [Tue Jan 24 14:05:52 GMT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Killed
```

- Why is the performance being affected?
- Is it a memory issue? How can I solve it?
- How can I prevent my containerized java apps from being killed?

I am using the same Dockerfile for the applications (each of them changes the ADD command):

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD archimedes-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]
```

I am wondering if it is necessary to provide the -Xms and -Xmx flags to force a minimum/maximum available memory...

On the other hand, the more containers I start, the less responsive the applications are...but Window's task manager doesn't show any CPU/RAM exhaustion. Maybe I have to tune the Windows Docker installation?

The code is available here: https://github.com/codependent/storyteller-microservices/tree/high-availability-rxjava

To start every microservice, under every folder there's a startContainer.sh that shows the docker commands I am using, for instance:

```
mvn clean package docker:build -DskipTests
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=archimedes1" -p 8761:8761 \
  --name archimedes1 --add-host archimedes1:192.168.99.100 --add-host archimedes2:192.168.99.100 --add-host my-rabbit:192.168.99.100 \
  -d storyteller/archimedes 
docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=archimedes2" -p 8762:8762 \
  --name archimedes2 --add-host archimedes1:192.168.99.100 --add-host archimedes2:192.168.99.100 --add-host my-rabbit:192.168.99.100 -d storyteller/archimedes
```

Comment: There's not much information to go on.

Comment: I added some more info. If you can think of something I can provide to help determine this, please tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by assigning more memory to the VirtualBox: in the settings view, System tab --> Base Memory 4GB.

With this the containers run smoothly and aren't being killed.